# NSBundle crash when setting string name as number?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to play some sound, that its name is a number . so i create an `NSString` as number, and when i try to set it to the `NSBundle`, it is Null!
It does work with a word, such as @"yes" , as the `name` parameter

```
//name parameter only works as a string in words. when its a number it doesn't.
     NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:type];
        NSLog(@"%@",name); //logs 16 !
        NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath]; //crash!
```

the crash is because the soundFilePath is nil .

```
NSString *number=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",16];
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Problem is that i had to add the sounds into the `build phase-copy bundle resources`, so he can find  them.